# List of universal properties

Tags: category-theory, higher-category-theory

At the moment I am looking into category theory and I am wondering if there exists a list of universal properties? I couldn't seem to find one.

Comment: Everything has a universal property. It's a really long list.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I wrote [some notes](https://www.pdf-archive.com/2016/12/17/categorytheory/categorytheory.pdf) that list out some of the ones I use most frequently, but as Qiaochu Yuan says in the comments, there is no hope of there being a complete list.

Comment: Your link is dead, could it be updated?

Comment: @ZelosMalum: Updated, guess they finally got around to deleting my UW page